# HTML DOM Select not working as expected on lit-html

Tags: lit-element, lit-html

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my code or it's an existing bug with lit-html?

I'm trying to get value of the selected item when button is clicked.

`number.js`

```
<select class="form-control" name="number">
     <option ?selected=${this.number === 1} value="1">One</option>
     <option ?selected=${this.number === 2} value="2">Two</option>
     <option ?selected=${this.number === 3} value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<button type="button" @click=${getSelectedValue}>Get Selected Value</button>


getSelectedValue() {
  const selectOptions = this.querySelector('select[name="number"]');

  const selectedValue = selectOptions.options[selectOptions.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

I've tried `selectOptions.value` but I still can't get the selected value.

Note that, I've added `createRenderRoot() {return this;}` to disable the shadowDOM.

Comment: Because lit-html and lit-element use the ShadowDOM, you must call this.shadowRoot.querySelector('select[name="number"]');

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention, I disabled the shadow DOM, I added. `createRenderRoot() {return this}` in it.

Comment: What does `selectOptions.selectedOptions` return?

Comment: It returns the selected options
`HTMLCollection [option]
 0: option
 length: 1`